# How to get an object at an index of a to-many NSSet in NSMangedObject category

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

Here is my sitch.  Let's say that I have Company and Employee object types, with company having to-many Employee's.  I create a category for Company and add a method

```
-(Employee *)getNextEmployee {
    return (Employee *)self.employees[self.currentEmployeeIndex++];
}
```

I realize that I can't access an NSSet by an index, but since it's a category I can't add an NSArray instance variable either.  This method is being called frequently, so creating an NSArray for each call would be highly inefficient.

Again, please ignore specifics here, it's just an example.

Comment: Your getNextEmployee method violates the Cocoa naming conventions. You almost certainly want to use fast enumeration to iterate over the results of an NSFetchRequest or the values in a Core Data relationship. Does the sequence really matter to you, or do you just need to hit all Employee instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both @danh and @pedro.m gave great answers.  I ended doing kind of a mixture of the two. I created a new class to manage my process instead of a subclass, and I pulled the employees straight from the relationship attribute of the company.  Something like this:

```
@implementation CompanyProcessRunner

-(void)setCompany:(Company *)newCompany
{
    company = newCompany;
    employees = [company.employees sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSSortDescriptor descriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES]];
}

-(Employee *)nextEmployee
{
    company.currentEmployeeIndex += 1;
    return (Employee *)[employees objectAtIndex:company.currentEmployeeIndex];
}

@end
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Are you sure about the sort descriptor array? Normally it has to contain `NSSortDescriptor`s, like in @pedro.m 's answer - but maybe there is a shortcut that I am not aware of.

Comment: It compiled, but I haven't actually had time to get around to running it.  That said, I believe that you are correct.  What's the point of a compiled language if it isn't going to give you compiler errors ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Scratch my previous answer suggesting the use of the allObjects property of NSSet. Thinking about it made me realize allObjects is not guaranteed to return the array on the same order every time.

Instead I suggest you use a linked list. Create a previousEmployee property for your Employee class and every time you create a new Employee, using some logic you assign the previous employee. It could be based on the date of entry:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Employee"];
request.fetchLimit = 1;

NSSortedDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [sortDescriptorWithKey:@"entryDate" ascending:NO];

// Do further setup...

Employee *latestEmployee = // fetch result...

Employee *newEmployee = // create new employee

newEmployee.previousEmployee = latestEmployee;
```

Comment: Looks like according to the docs that it does not return them in any specific order.

Comment: Maybe not even in a consistent order over time, say if adds and removes occur.

Comment: Yes, I realized that as soon as I sent the answer in. Working on a new answer now!

Comment: Remember NSFetchRequest is very optimal, specially if you set your request to return one object only.

Answer (score 1):

There's no getting around having an array if you want ordering (implied by next).  The way to have an array economically is to make a NSManagedObject subclass and add an array property to it.  Update it when you do adds/removes from the set.

Comment: So instead of a category I subclass my NSManagedObject?

Comment: Yes, I just read your "since it's in a category".  A subclass is the way to go.

Comment: From what I've read, it is recommended not to edit the subclass created by "Create NSManagedObject Subclass" so that you can allow Xcode to regenerate it, henceforth the reason for the category. Do you think I should subclass that subclass or edit directly?

Comment: I haven't done a core data app in awhile, but I would edit those all the time.  Was unaware of any advice against it.

Comment: Maybe it's time for me to get out of the "intro" books and into some more advanced ones ;-)

Comment: :-)  Looks to be okay with Apple.  See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/03_ManagedObject.html about 2/3 down "Custom Managed Object Class"